# How can I get the index of the row where a value has a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good morning,

I have a dataframe that has only values of True and False and  want to get the row index where the value True exits.
I tried this:

```
[i for i in df_str[df_str.columns.values] if i== True]
```

But this return an empty array.
How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for 'True' in a single column, or at any column in the dataframe?

Comment: @Roy2012 yes, I am searching got True values and I want the index

Comment: Again - in a specific column in the dataframe, or in one of many columns? What's the structure of the input?

Comment: @Roy2012 in all column I want to search

Comment: kindly provide sample data with expected output

Comment: I am unable to understand how Umer's answer is different than @Roy2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do that. I'm using synthetic data for the sake of demonstration.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.choice([True, False], 10), 
              "b": np.random.choice([True, False], 10)}) 

print(df)
#        a      b
# 0  False   True
# 1   True  False
# 2  False   True
# 3   True   True
# 4  False  False
# 5   True  False
# 6  False   True
# 7   True  False
# 8   True  False
# 9   True   True

# 'a' and 'b' are the columns you'd like to search
df[df[["a", "b"]].sum(axis=1) > 0].index.to_list()
# ==> [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
# for single column
df.index[df['col_name'] == True].tolist()

#for multiple columns
df[df[["a", "b"]].sum(axis=1) > 0].index.to_list()
```

Comment: I want to search in all columns , not a specific one

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the indices where `True` is present (for the provided sample) is to use `any`. The following code will give you all the indices where any value in a particular row is `True`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[True, False, False, True],"B":[True, True, False, False]})
indices=df[df.any(axis=1)].index
```

**Expected Output**

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 3], dtype='int64')
```